# Starcraft 2: Blizzard Downloader has Encountered a Problem

Tags: wine

Not sure if anyone else has had this problem, but the downloader got to 30% and crashed. It seems now to crash every time it checks itself back to 30%. Program freezes and I have to terminate it.

Anyone have any solutions?

I suppose the work around for this is to just torrent the DVD's instead. But it would be really nice to get this working.

I installed the vcrun2005 and 2008
I am WINEARCH=win64
Windows Xp

Comment: For reference to anyone else, StarCraft II has a [gold compatibility rating at WineHQ's AppDB](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882).

Comment: localised issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove the files that the were downloaded by the installer and try again. There seems to be a fault that cannot be recovered in them. They are located (generally) in your `~/.wine/` folder, the default location is the user's desktop folder `c_drive`>`Documents and Settings`>`user`>`Desktop`.

After deleting the installed files you need to try to download them again.

Another option is to look for a torrent with the files for offline for offline installing but there are no real direct secure sources, you will have to risk installing the game from an unsecured source and most of the times that is really not an good option.

**Extra information**

To fully install and run Starcraft2 will will need to do the following:

- Your wine bottle version should be WindowsXP 32bits.
- Install `libmpg123-0` in your system (look for it in `USC` or install
  it `sudo apt-get install libmpg123-0`)
- Install in your wine bottle Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 Service Pack 1
  from [this
  location](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14431).
  The file you need to use is `vcredist_x86.exe`.

Comment: Thanks, thats to bad it crashed again at 20% this time. Seems like its just crashing all the time. I suppose I will torrent the DVD's. I look a the wine output and it just had some weird memory address error and started the debugger (assuming debugger was reason proc went zombie).

Comment: Added extra information about starcraft2 installation, just tested this on my system (11.10 32bits), it just works. Are you using wine from the Ubuntu repos or wine PPA?

Comment: Wine PPA, I am 64x and I am installing your libmpg123-0 now. Maybe it will fix my issue :d Fingers Crossed :D I managed to install from dvd but the DVD I downloaded was wrong version fml. I still cant get downloader to download the NA edition. Was thinking about using a VMWare to download SC then copying the files out of the vmware to install them... what do you think?

Comment: better option then downloading some weird stuff from the net ;) just make sure you are using a windowsxp 32bit bottle for the install, the libmpg123 is for the audio during the install, really hope this works and if not drop a comment. gl

Comment: I think i will need the 64bit version of the redist, but thanks!!!